# ActiveRecord: returning objects belonging to an Ancestry nodetree

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Category model, which uses the Ancestry gem to create a tree hierarchy. If I have the model relationship,

```
Category has_many :posts
```

I'm wondering how I can return posts belonging to a category or children of that category. category.subtree returns an ARel object, so I could do something like:

```
category.subtree.includes(:posts)
```

which maps posts by category but I just want the posts. The only thing I can think to do is iterating over the collection and create a new collection of just posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Post.where('category_id in (?)', category.subtree_ids)
```

I don't remember at the moment, if subtree_ids will return also id of category itself.

Comment: Awesome. That worked! And yes, it appears that subtree_ids also returns the id of the category itself.